# When does OOM gets invoked to kill some process in linux kernel version 5.x.x?

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, out-of-memory

Is it possible for a Linux kernel OOM killer to kill a process even if there is enough swap space available?
This [link](https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand016.html) in section 13.2 suggests that if there is a swap space available then OOM killer will not kill a process.

Now, I made changes to the Linux kernel and stopped the swapping of anonymous pages entirely, and consequently, there is always a free swap space available. But still, I observe OOM killing processes.

However, this documentation may be outdated. Can someone provide insights into what are the checks performed before OOM really kills a process in the latest Linux kernel(v-5.x.x)?

Comment: Check your `/proc/sys/vm/min_free_kbytes` variable. Any time your free memory falls below that variable, in my experience, the OOM killer will be called regardless of swap space.

Comment: @wxz, AFAIK and as per what I observed OOM would not get called if there is enough swap space available. But I wanted to know what are the exact policies currently employed in Linux kernel with regard to invoking OOM.

Comment: out_of_memory is called when alloc_page fails. swap is not checked.